# Making Kubuntu start on command line

Tags: kubuntu, login

How can I make Kubuntu (14.04) start (by default) on the command line and not in graphical mode?

Every post seems to deal with the reverse of this, namely that for some reason, *buntu starts on the command line and the user is trying to get it to start on graphical mode.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (you can open a terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
use the following command

```
sudo update-rc.d -f kdm remove
```

It will still boot and shutdown graphically but you can disables the splash screen in the grub using the following commands

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

remove `"quiet splash"` from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` entry
enter the following command to update your grub

```
sudo update-grub2
```

reboot

Comment: An alternative solution would be to remove kdm and use startx to start KDE Plasma (sudo apt-get remove kdm).

Comment: @Arno: when you say "remove" from grub file, do you mean "just erase" what is after the "=" sign? or do I have to put something else in it's place (like "false" or "none").

Comment: Update: I tried both with     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""    and    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=    and in both cases I can see the text of everything loading up, but when it's time to login, the graphical login page is still there. So, so far no luck.

Comment: hmmm, could you change the "quiet splash" to "text" and do an update of your grub?? If that doesn't work try executing `echo "manual" > /etc/init/gdm.override`